# Как правильно написать программу, которая вычисляет формулу?

Tags: c, ассемблер, x86

Я пытался сделать программу, которая будет вычислять значение этой формулы:

> `(4b + c - d) (2b + 5(3c + 5a)) / (4ab + 5c - 8d)`

Я попробовал написать хоть что-то, но совершенно ничего не происходит. Код — полный бред, который даже не компилируется.

Вопрос. Как написать правильный код? Не знаю, может это и тупой вопрос…

```
Data segment
Mess db 'Результат : ', '$'
a  dw 0
b  dw 0
c  dw 0
d  dw 0
Data ends

Code segment use16
assume cs: Code, ds: Data
Start:
mov ax, Data
mov ds, ax

PrtChr '>'
InputInt a

PrtChr '>'
InputInt b

PrtChr '>'
InputInt c

PrtChr '>'
InputInt d

Print Mess, 0
 
mov ax, b        ; ax = b
mov cx, 4        ; cx = 4
imul cx;         ; b * 4
add cx, c        ; b * 4 + c
sub cx, d        ; b * 4 + c - d

mov ax, 2        ; ax = 2
mov al, b        ; al = b
imul al          ; b * 2
mov ax, 5        ; ax = 5
 
mov cl, 3        ; cl = 3
mov ch, c        ; ch = c
imul ch          ; c * 3
mov ecx, 5       ; ecx = 5
mov eax, a       ; eax = a
imul eax         ; a * 5
add ch, eax      ; ch = (3*c + 5*a)

imul ch          ; 5 * (3 * c + 5 * a)
add al, ch       ; (2 * b + (5 * ( 3 * c + 5 * a ) ) )

move ah, cx      ; ah = b * 4 + c - d
move eax, al     ; eax = (2 * b + (5 * ( 3 * c + 5 * a ) ) )
imul eax         ; eax = (b * 4 + c - d) * (2 * b + (5 * ( 3 * c + 5 * a ) ) )

; 4 * a * b
move ax, 4       ; ax = 4
move ah, a       ; ah = a
imul ah          ; 4 * a
move ah, ah
move ax, b       ; ax = b
imul ax          ; 4 * a * b

; 5 * c
move ah, 5
move al, c
imul al

; 4 * a * b + 5 * c
add ah, al

; 8 * d
move al, 8      ; al = 8
move ecx, d     ; ecx = d
imul ecx        ; d * 8

; 4 * a * b + 5 * c - 8 * d
sub ah, ecx

KeyPressed

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
Code ends

Stk segment STACK
dw 128 dup(?)
Stk ends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расскажу вам небольшой секрет, который сохранит вам многие часы жизни:

> Если вам дали задание написать что-то на ассемблере, то **не надо писать это на ассемблере** — напишите код на C, а потом скомпилируйте и посмотрите, какой ассемблерный код сгенерировал компилятор.

Например, в вашем случае, пишем нужную программу на C:

```c
void
calc(void)
{
    /* Значения могут быть любыми. */
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 5;
    int d = 7;

    int result = (4 * b + c - d) * (2 * b + 5 * (3 * c + 5 * a)) / (4 * a * b + 5 * c - 8 * d);
}
```

Затем компилируем её с выключенной оптимизацией ([`-O0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)) и с выдачей ассемблерного листинга ([`-S`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)). Флаги `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` и `-fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm` сделают ассемблерный листинг [немного чище](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116/8086115):

```bsh
# p.c — название файла с исходным кодом
gcc -O0 -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm p.c
```

На выходе получаем вот такой вот ассемблерный листинг:

```
    .file   "p.c"
    .text
    .globl  calc
    .type   calc, @function
calc:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $2, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $3, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $7, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    leal    0(,%rax,4), %edx
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    subl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rax), %esi
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rdx), %edi
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sall    $2, %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    leal    (%rdi,%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    sall    $2, %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    addl    %esi, %eax
    imull   %eax, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edx
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    imull   -16(%rbp), %eax
    leal    0(,%rax,4), %esi
    movl    -12(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    sall    $2, %eax
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    leal    (%rsi,%rax), %ecx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    sall    $3, %eax
    subl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    cltd
    idivl   %ecx
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .size   calc, .-calc
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Иногда бывает удобнее использовать такой инструмент как [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

---

Если вы занимаетесь для себя и хотите научится писать на ассемблере — все то же самое. Попытайтесь написать программу сами, если не получается, напишите тот же самый код на C и посмотрите, во что компилятор его перевел, какие конструкции ассемблера он использовал.

Пробуйте переводить C в ассемблер в ручную: берете распечатку кода на C и на соседнем листочке пишете ассемблерный код (можно и без распечатки, конечно). Не обязательно переводить большие программы, можете начать с небольших кусочков кода типа

```c
int a = 4;         // movl $4, -4(%rbp)
int b = 7;         // movl $7, -8(%rbp)
                   // movl -4(%rbp), %edx
                   // movl -8(%rbp), %eax
                   // addl %edx, %eax
int c = a + b;     // movl %eax, -12(%rbp)
```

```c
int a = 5;         //   movl $5, -4(%rbp)
                   //   jmp .L2
                   // .L3:
while (a > 0) {    //   movl $0, %eax
    foo();         //   call foo
    a--;           //   subl $1, -4(%rbp)
}                  // .L2:
                   //   cmpl $0, -4(%rbp)
                   //   jg .L3
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но с вопрос, что делать, если Ассемблер (ASMedit) не знает ничего про регистры rax, rbp итд. При попытке компиляции возвращается ошибка Undefined symbol: RAX, например. Как это исправить?

Comment: @ЗлойШкальник, выбросьте ASMedit и возьмите, например, [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/). Только учтите, что есть два основных синтаксиса ассемблера x86: AT&T и Intel. NASM использует синтаксис Intel, а GCC по-умолчанию будет выдавать в синтаксисе AT&T. Поищите как заставить GCC использовать синтаксис Intel, либо используйте [godblot.org](https://godbolt.org/), который по-умолчанию использует Intel.